# Can 10.0.0.0/8 network range used for public ip?

Tags: networking, ip, ftp, bittorrent

Recently I used utorrent, where I saw that it was fetching files from ip of the range 10.0.0.0/8 which were running ftp service. But in computer networking I learned that 10.0.0.0/8 range is used for private ip. So please clear my doubt of this range

Comment: Your question does not seem to be security related. Please remove it here and ask on [SU]

Comment: Bit torrent is using "Local Peer Discovery" to download files from local LAN when available.

Comment: Remember your "local lan" in this case could be your entire ISP's network, it is not uncommon for you to NOT be handed a public IP address, but an address in private space... it's called Enterprise NAT.

Answer (score 0):

The address range is reserved as "private", but that merely means that ISPs of the world have agreed to not accept any routes for it, and that the meaning of such addresses varies from place to place.

However, it doesn't really limit how broad the "private" usage might be – it might be building-wide, company-wide, even ISP-wide or country-wide. My ISP uses 10./8 for its device management; my $WORK uses 10./8 for its LAN that spans six buildings, and is connected to a country-wide "secure" network that also uses 10./8. Some ISPs, who have run out of global addresses, use CGNAT and provide all customers with private addresses only.

So you might be seeing another host on your own network, found via PEX or LPD or such.